# ¿Por qué "quizá" puede llevar el verbo en subjuntivo pero "a lo mejor" no?

Tags: subjuntivo, adverbios, locuciones

La definición de *quizá* según el DLE es:

> **[quizá](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UxdCUVe)**
>
> Del ant. *quiçab[e]*, y este alterac. de *qui sabe* 'quién sabe'.
>
> 1. adv. Denota la posibilidad de que ocurra o sea cierto lo que se expresa.

Es decir, la palabra *quizá* se usa para hablar de hechos no contrastados, de sucesos probables, luego es terreno propicio para el uso del subjuntivo. De hecho dos de los ejemplos que da el diccionario son:

> *Quizá llueva mañana.
>
>   Quizá sea verdad lo que dice.*

La locución adverbial *[tal vez](http://dle.rae.es/?id=biPx6YF#AO4e3SY)*, sinónima de *quizá*, también lo usa:

> *Tal vez llueva mañana.
>
>   Tal vez sea verdad lo que dice.*

Sin embargo, y tal y [como dice el DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=mejor):

> A diferencia de sus equivalentes *quizá* y *tal vez*, que normalmente llevan el verbo en subjuntivo (aunque también admitan su uso con indicativo), *[a lo mejor](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OnhZjCP#822Vg2y)* y *[a la mejor](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OnhZjCP#Dd7gYNB)* llevan siempre el verbo en indicativo.

Por tanto, aunque *a lo mejor* equivalga a las dos anteriores, tenemos que decir:

> *A lo mejor llueve mañana.
>
>   A lo mejor es verdad lo que dice.*

¿Qué tiene de especial esta locución adverbial para que impida el uso del verbo en subjuntivo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resulta que la premisa de la que parto en la pregunta, extraída del DPD, se centra en el español europeo. Al respecto del uso de *a lo mejor* con los modos indicativo y subjuntivo, la *Gramática* española [dice](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=SuQdyOjJRzFVoPoB):

> **25.14n** La locución adverbial *a lo mejor* se construye asimismo con ambos modos, si bien alcanza más extensión el indicativo que el subjuntivo [...]. La proporción de los usos con subjuntivo es ligeramente mayor en el español americano que en el europeo.

Y cita los siguientes ejemplos:

> A lo mejor no sepa cómo insurgió Caldera a la vida política.
>   A lo mejor se hubiera muerto ya desde hace rato.
>   A lo mejor lo hubiera apartado.

Por último comenta que la variante *a la mejor*, usada en el español oral de México, se construye casi siempre con indicativo.

Por tanto, como respuesta decir que no es que la locución *a lo mejor* no admita el subjuntivo, sino que permite ambos modos. Simplemente en el uso la forma con indicativo se ha extendido hasta el punto de que usarlo con subjuntivo puede "sonar raro".

Answer (score 1):

Una pregunta muy interesante. Mi explicación es la siguiente. Tanto "quizá" como "tal vez", usados con subjuntivo, vienen a significar `es posible que`, y por tanto, al hablar de posibilidades, rigen un subjuntivo es muchos casos.

Aunque como bien dices, no siempre utilizan subjuntivo, y es sencillo encontrar ejemplos con indicativo. En esos casos, "quizá" significa lo mismo que "a lo mejor".

Y es que, tal como yo lo veo, "a lo mejor", o "en el mejor de los casos", son expresiones que introducen **una opinión**, y eso es una afirmación cierta, un hecho, luego llevan indicativo.

Más bien, afirman que hay una posibilidad. Por lo tanto es una afirmación.

> Quizá llueva = es posible que llueva.
>
> A lo mejor llueve = el hecho de que llueva **es** una posibilidad.